# Populate rows with the sheets names of an spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have an spreadsheet that contains multiple sheets with some recipes. I'm storing the sheets' titles in the first sheet manually, to reference the recipes titles on another spreadsheet, but this doesn't scale well, so I want to automate the process. I believe I can't do that with any of the built in functions, so I'm trying to build a custom function to do it.

I already know some coding, but my experience with google API is very limited. My current attempt is returning the following exception: "You do not have the permission to call set value". After google this error, I discovered that custom functions seemingly cannot set values to another cells, so I'm here to find an alternative to such a trivial behavior.

This is my current code:

```
function updateSheetTitles() {
  var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
  var cell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getCurrentCell();
  var row = cell.getRow();
  var column = cell.getColumn();
  for (var i=0 ; i<sheets.length ; i++){
    if(i<1) //For passing trought the first sheet
      return;
    cell.setValue(sheets[i].getSheetName);
    var range = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(row+1, column, 1, 1);
    cell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().setCurrentCell(range);
  }
}
```

And here's and image to illustrate what I want:

[image]

This is probably an easy task, but I failed to find a way to build this, so any ideas to accomplish that would be appreciated.

Comment: The workaround to be able to set other cells is to run your script from a menu as a normal server function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to retrieve sheet names in the active Google Spreadsheet.
- You want to put the sheet names to the active cell.
- You want to achieve this using the custom function.

#### Modification points:

- Unfortunately, `setValue` cannot be used in the custom function. I think that the reason of your issue is due to this.
- In your script, at `cell.setValue(sheets[i].getSheetName);`, the method of `getSheetName` is not run. If you want to use this method, please add `()` like `getSheetName()`.
- `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()` can be declared one time.

In order to achieve your goal, I would like to propose a custom function for creating an array including the sheet names and returning the array.

When above points are reflected to the sample script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Google Spreadsheet. And, please put the custom function of `=updateSheetTitles()` to a cell. By this, the sheet names are returned to the row direction.

```
function updateSheetTitles() {
  return SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets().map(e => [e.getSheetName()]);
}
```

- From your replying, when you want to retrieve the sheet names except for 1st and 2nd sheet, you can also use the following script.

  ```
    function updateSheetTitles() {
      return SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets().map(e => [e.getSheetName()]).slice(2);
    }
  ```

#### References:

- [Custom Functions in Google Sheets](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions)
- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [getSheetName()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getsheetname)

Comment: Many thanks man, you got it, almost there. I need to exclude the first 2 sheet titles, that is, the return must get the title from the third sheet onwards. I would make this change myself if I've had a better understanding of your solution.

Comment: @Gabriel Minosso Thank you for replying. For your additional question, I added one more sample script in my answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question, I apologize.